# Calendar in javascript with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, calendar

```
var year = 2014 ; 
var dagen = new Array("Mo ", "Tu ", "Wed ", "Th ", "Fri ", "Sat ", "Sun ");
var dag = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

document.write("<h2>januari</h2> <br> <br>");
for(i = 0 ; i < dagen.length ; i++)
{
    document.write(dagen[i]);

     if( i == 2)
    {
        for(x = 0 ; x < dag.length ; x++)
        document.write(dag[x])
    }
    else{
    }    

}
```

Hi I've got a question to ask about how to write my code. The thing is what I get now is:

```
Mo Tu Wed 12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031Th Fri Sat Sun.
```

And what I want is that the `1,2,3` etc go below the `Mo, Tu, Wed` so it looks like a calender and also binds them together like what a real calender does.

Example: when its 13th it goes to monday. What I also want it that u can put something inside the `1,2,3` etc like an input box but it also saves it.

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: You should consider using jQuery [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).  Writing your own calendar date picker is going to be hard and you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can use the native Date object in JavaScript